# Using style triggers on a static resource style to change more than properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using Material Design XAML and I am trying to set a togglebutton icon and background color to something else when checked.

[image]

***RED BOX CODE***

```
<ToggleButton ToolTip="MaterialDesignFlatPrimaryToggleButton"
              IsChecked="False"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Margin="78,58,99,52"
              Grid.Row="1">
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatPrimaryToggleButton}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

***GREEN BOX CODE***

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatPrimaryToggleButton}"
              ToolTip="MaterialDesignFlatPrimaryToggleButton"
              IsChecked="False"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              Grid.Column="3"
              Margin="205,58,188,52"
              Grid.Row="1">
    <md:PackIcon Kind="WindowClose"
                 Foreground="Red"
                 Height="21"
                 Width="21"/>
</ToggleButton>
```

I was thinking I could use the basedon attribute to reserve the style with material design...if possible.

I am trying reserve the style and change the icon and set background color when checked to look like this:

[image]

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently setting the `Style` as the `ToggleButton.Content`.
You've got to define the `Style` nested into the `ToggleButton.Style` property:

```
<ToggleButton ToolTip="MaterialDesignFlatPrimaryToggleButton"
          IsChecked="False"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Margin="78,58,99,52"
          Grid.Row="1">
  <ToggleButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatPrimaryToggleButton}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />

          <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
              <md:PackIcon Kind="SmileyHappy" />
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ToggleButton.Style>    
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Yes that part is right! Thank you but i'm also confused on how I can change pack icon since it's not a property?

Comment: The icon is assigned to the `ToggleButton.Content` property. I updated the answer to show setting a different icon using the `Setter`.

Comment: So this isn't isn't changing the content, or is it just not updating the view?

Comment: fixed it using datatemplate, thank you @BionicCode !

Comment: Good that you've fixed it. In my example the icon will changed once the `ToggleButton` is checked. This is because the icon is added via a style setter of a trigger. You can move the setter out of the trigger to change the icon permanently.